# What is regex for currency symbol?

Tags: python, regex

In java I can use the regex : [`\p{Sc}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) for detecting currency symbol in text. What is the equivalent in Python?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use the unicode category if you use [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) package:

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.findall(r'\p{Sc}', '$99.99 / €77')  # Python 3.x
['$', '€']
```

---

```
>>> regex.findall(ur'\p{Sc}', u'$99.99 / €77')  # Python 2.x (NoteL unicode literal)
[u'$', u'\xa2']
>>> print _[1]
¢
```

**UPDATE**

Alterantive way using [`unicodedata.category`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.category):

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> [ch for ch in '$99.99 / €77' if unicodedata.category(ch) == 'Sc']
['$', '€']
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that 'regex' package is different from 're' package.

Comment: `regex` is *awesome*. [That's just the tip of the iceberg.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex)

Answer (score 31):

If you want to stick with [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re), supply the [characters from Sc manually](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sc/list.htm):

```
u"[$¢£¤¥֏؋৲৳৻૱௹฿៛\u20a0-\u20bd\ua838\ufdfc\ufe69\uff04\uffe0\uffe1\uffe5\uffe6]"
```

will do.

Comment: Which of these is the Euro symbol?

Comment: That's contained in `\u20a0-\u20bd`: € is `\u20ac`.

Comment: You can automate the generation of the set of currency characters: `currency_symbols = u''.join(unichr(i) for i in range(0xffff) if unicodedata.category(unichr(i)) == 'Sc')`