# Find currency code in price string

Tags: python

I have prices similar to:

```
$ 1.99
2,99 €
```

How would I extract the currency symbol? It should be 'space + symbol' or 'symbol + space'. Here is what I currently have, but it's not working for the second case:

```
s='2,99 €'
>>> re.findall('\s\w',s)
```

What would be the best way to extract the currency symbol?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is regex for currency symbol?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978771/what-is-regex-for-currency-symbol)

Answer (score 1):

I know this one doesn't use `re`, but it could be helpful. Split the string and just check if it has the symbol:

```
s = '2,99 €'
for i in s.split(' '):
    if i == '€':
        # That's my currency!
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know it's going to be at the start or the end then just check there?

```
currency_code = None
currency_codes = ("$", "€", )
if len(s) > 0:
    if s[0] in currency_codes:
       currency_code = s[0]
    elif s[-1] in currency_codes:
       currency_code = s[-1]
```

You can do it with regex of course, but that seems like overkill for this?

Answer (score 0):

it's very-very ghetto but...

```
import string
filter = string.digits + ' ,.'
currency = [ch for ch in s if ch not in filter][0]
```