# How to tokenize all currency symbols using Regex in python?

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk, tokenize

I want to tokenize all the symbols of currency by using NLTK tokenize with regex.

For example this is my sentence:

```
The price of it is $5.00.
The price of it is RM5.00.
The price of it is €5.00.
```

I used this pattern of regex:

```
pattern = r'''(['()""\w]+|\.+|\?+|\,+|\!+|\$?\d+(\.\d+)?%?)'''
tokenize_list = nltk.regexp_tokenize(sentence, pattern)
```

But as we can see it only considers $.

I tried to use `\p{Sc}` as explained in [What is regex for currency symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978771/what-is-regex-for-currency-symbol) but it is still not working for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is regex for currency symbol?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978771/what-is-regex-for-currency-symbol)

Comment: I tried to use the same way but still couldn't get the right answer. @b3000

Comment: Can you show your attempt to use `\p{Sc}` and why it is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pad the numbering with the currency symbol with spaces then tokenize:

```
>>> import re
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> sents = """The price of it is $5.00.
... The price of it is RM5.00.
... The price of it is €5.00.""".split('\n')
>>>
>>> for sent in sents:
...     numbers_in_sent = re.findall("[-+]?\d+[\.]?\d*", sent)
...     for num in numbers_in_sent:
...             sent = sent.replace(num, ' '+num+' ')
...     print word_tokenize(sent)
... 
['The', 'price', 'of', 'it', 'is', '$', '5.00', '.']
['The', 'price', 'of', 'it', 'is', 'RM', '5.00', '.']
['The', 'price', 'of', 'it', 'is', '\xe2\x82\xac', '5.00', '.']
```